# How do you read the symbol “x” when used instead of a preposition?

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases, symbols

For example: “Adidas x Stella McCartney “ or “Stan Smith x Adidas”
One of the most known uses I can think of is on “SXSW” and here the “X” is read as “By.”

Is it correct to use it instead of the preposition “Of” or "For"?

To me is more natural to read it as in "By."

For example: in mathematics, the symbol × has a number of uses, including

—Multiplication of two scalar numbers, where it is read as **"times"** or **"multiplied by"** 
—Cross product of two vectors, where it is usually read as "cross"
—Cartesian product of two sets, where it is usually read as "cross"
—Geometric dimension of an object, such as noting that a room is **10 feet × 12 feet in area, where it is usually read as "by" (for example: "10 feet by 12 feet")**
—**Dimensions of a matrix, where it is usually read as "by"**
—**A statistical interaction** between two explanatory variables, where it is usually read as **"by"**

Comment: What's the context of the examples in the first paragraph?

Comment: The examples I provided in the first paragraph are how often brands advertise projects in conjunction with other brands / people.

Comment: It’s likely ***by***:  https://www.adidas.com/us/adidas_by_stella_mccartney

Comment: It's "south by southwest", which is clearly a play of words on Hitchcock's film "North by Northwest", which itself a non-existent compass point (the real compass point is "northwest by north"; Hitchcock's title was a play on words itself).

Comment: There has been a lot of promiscuous misspelling for media purposes lately, especially of the much-misused letter `x`. I'm thinking of _Latinx_, which always plays off as /la'tɪŋks/ in my mind's ear, and _Womxn_, which looks quite unpronounceable and seems to try to distinguish between singular and plural, even though the first vowel is what changes. Stick an `x` on something and suddenly it's Xtreme.

Comment: I think when using the x to replace a vowel that indicates gender inclusion there’s not that much confusion. My question was specific when used instead of a preposition.

Comment: Don't forget *Xmas*.  And *Malcolm X*.

Comment: I read the x as versus: “Adidas *versus* Stella McCartney."

Comment: How can the main uses, i.e. times, by or versus not allow one to define this? That does not include x as an unknown, of course.

Comment: There is no established usage for ***x*** in these kinds of constructions in English, and therefore no way of pronouncing it that would be established in the language. The question is thus unanswerable on a site devoted to English language and usage. If one wants to know how the advertisers who deliberately misused ***x*** in this way intended it to be pronounced, one should ask them.

Comment: Further to jsw29's Comment, you should find more suitable help at, for instance, SE English Language Learners.

Answer (score 1):

The points of the compass do not have a "South by Southwest" and the "by" is abbreviated "b".

Moving clockwise from South, we have:

south by west (SbW); south southwest (SSW), southwest by south (SWbS), southwest (SW). See Wiki at [32 Compass Points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_of_the_compass#32_compass_points)

As far as "Adidas x Stella McCartney" is concerned, I found this on the [Harvey Nichols](https://www.harveynichols.com/brand/adidas-x-stella-mccartney/) site. I would read it as ""Adidas **designed by** Stella McCartney"

There is also the biological use to indicate a hybrid, e.g. a **liger** is *Panthera tigris* × *Panthera leo*. Here, 'x' = crossed[bred] with.

"X" is only understandable in context. There is no rule (but I think you already knew that.)

Comment: @jsw29 It answers him by correcting the errors that he has seen. He now knows that, as far as direction is concerned, "x" is as much a mistake as spelling, for example "contain" as "contane".

Comment: The examples are myriad. "X" is a symbol whose meaning is only available through context. Even the "by" translation does not explain 4" x 6" as having the same meaning as  southwest by south. I have added to my answer.

Comment: @Davo I'd be obliged if you could point out "SbSW" as the "Control+F" function produces no results for this and neither does the search term "south by southwest" or "south by south west"

Comment: My mistake, I misread that.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen this usage before, but here it clearly means "by". For instance, [this size of timber](https://www.grangewoodfencing.com/product/4-x-3-timber-fence-posts-brown) would be written as "4 x 3" and pronounced "four by three".

"Of" makes no sense here.

Comment: unless it means 12

Comment: Sorry I meant "For" instead,  and I agree with you. To me, make sense when is being used as "by".

Answer (score 0):

Absent (the sorely lacking) context, I would interpret “Adidas x Stella McCartney” and “Stan Smith x Adidas” as identifying court cases/lawsuits, and hence would read the "x" as meaning "versus".

Comment: While I agree with you in general, the reference I found means that in OP’s case it means “by” as in “designed by”.

Answer (score -1):

I think X is used in a lot of ways and I would be wary of trying to form a hard rule.

With 2 people joined by an X, i would assume it indicates a romantic relationship, but it might means  a HATES b.

i've seen it used in SQL to mean join or cross.

If i had to make a rule, id say it means the union of two things... it is South and Southwest ...roughly in a direction on a heading of 202 degrees.

I would not suggest to you to substitute X freely for any other word.

Comment: +1 for the first sentence, which is the best answer because it covers everything.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Surely you mean it covers nothing?

Comment: It covers all uses of 'x' under discussion. There are too many and they're very context-sensitive, so forming any hard rule is impossible.

Comment: @JohnLawler SxSW is an error - it should not be used at all. See my answer and comment above.

Comment: @Greybeard  sxsw in a search engine yields 13.8M results. Vast majority  about the concert. While a cartographer would probably agree with you, it looks as if many people adopted, or would infer the usage. I did. And Im an eagle scout!  :-0   poking fun at myself here....